# Best way to use sessionStorage in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session-storage

I'm pretty new to AngularJS and I try to implement a litte Ionic App as clean as possible.

My app contains a controller for login which store the logged user in the $rootScope but I've read that using $rootScope isn't a good practices to share variables between controllers.

So I would like to use sessionStorage and localStorage but I wonder what are the best practices about it:

- Should my ServiceLogin service write directly in storage or send data to controller which become the only who can write in storage?
- Can/Should I use sessionStorage variable directly in html between {{ }} tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the answer is it depends...
It depends on the size and scope of your project and the "tidy" you want to be with your code. A simple test project just for experimenting is not the same as a big LOB application with lot of moving parts.

Anyway, to be "angularish" you should take the first path you've said, that is, making a service that saves data to localStorage and inject it and call it on the controllers/components that need this feature. There are some modules programmed out there that also have fallback to cookie storage or others, but I find this isn't necessary at all, since local/session storage is suported for quite long on the major browsers, even mobile ones. See [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage).

Reading your second option just makes my eyes sting... and won't work (making a call to window.getItem(...) from inside {{}}), at least until they release 1.6 version on wich they've removed the parser's sandbox. Anyway it's a bad practice and you should avoid it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! Project not really big but this is for a governemental services so the tiddier the better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think there's no problem that your service writes in storage. As for using storage variables directly in HTML, I'd say it's better to assign storage variables to your controller's `$scope` variable, as your `$scope` is the one that's exposed to the view.

To manipulate browser's storage, [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)'s your best bet.